# IBM Discovery: Tutorials, Docs for building Queries

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, watson-discovery

I am using IBM Watson News and are trying to find certain news articles. But I am struggling with the queries.
Which Tutorials, Docs did help you understand the query structure and possibilities?

E.g.: I am trying to find news articles related to IoT Projects between companies, how would you query this with Watson News?

but in general I would like to understand the query structure.

best
Jonas

Comment: This question is slightly off topic. Stackover is more for helping you solve an issue once you start working. So to ask how to use Watson overall is too broad

Comment: Hi Rufus, thanks for your comment. I get your point and totally agree. But since I am struggling to actually get started I didn't wonna miss the chance to learn from other people's experience. best

Comment: Jonas, try starting out with the online docs on Bluemix (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/using.html).  There is a section devoted to the Query API (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/query-reference.html) that will make more sense once you've read that.

Comment: This demo will show you some query examples to help you get started too https://discovery-news-demo-static.mybluemix.net/